# Problem with list value (ValueError) in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I am trying to create a simple card game for school, I am at the stage of coding how gameplay works within the game and am getting a ValueError when trying to remove a value from a list

I've already tried changing my `list.remove(x)` syntax, so far I have tried `list.remove(list[x])`, `list.remove([x])` and `list.remove(x)`, but all of these have returned a ValueError.

```py
import random, time #imports required modules for the code

cardDeck = []
player1 = []
player1CardsWon = []
player2 = []
player2CardsWon = [] #all these lists/arrays are needed later on in the code

def deckCreator(): #creates all the needed embedded lists inside the cardDeck 2D Array
  for color in ["yellow", "red", "black"]:
    for number in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
      cardDeck.append([color, number])

'''test 1 - to check if deckCreator function is working
deckCreator()
print(cardDeck)
'''

def deckShuffle(): #shuffles the cardDeck 2D Array
  random.shuffle(cardDeck)

'''test 2 - to check if the deckShuffle function is working
deckCreator()
print(cardDeck)
deckShuffle()
print(cardDeck)
'''

def gamePlay(): #plays a round of the game
  while len(cardDeck) > 0:
    time.sleep(2)
    player1 = cardDeck.pop(0)
    player2 = cardDeck.pop(0)
    print("Player 1 holds card", player1[0], player1[1], "for this round")
    print("Player 2 holds card", player2[0], player2[1], "for this round")
    if player1[0] == "yellow":
      if player2[0] == "red": #Yellow beats red
        player1CardsWon.append(player1)
        player1CardsWon.append(player2)
        player1.remove(0)
        player1.remove(1)
        player2.remove(0)
        player2.remove(1)
        print("Player 1 wins!")
      elif player2[0] == "black": #Black beats yellow
        player2CardsWon.append(player1)
        player2CardsWon.append(player2)
        player1.remove(0)
        player1.remove(1)
        player2.remove(0)
        player2.remove(1)
        print("Player 2 wins!")
      elif player2[0] == "yellow":
        if player1[1] > player2[1]:
          player1CardsWon.append(player1)
          player1CardsWon.append(player2)
          player1.remove(0)
          player1.remove(1)
          player2.remove(0)
          player2.remove(1)
          print("Player 1 wins!")
        else:
          player2CardsWon.append(player1)
          player2CardsWon.append(player2)
          player1.remove(0)
          player1.remove(1)
          player2.remove(0)
          player2.remove(1)
          print("Player 2 wins!")
    if player1[0] == "red":
      if player2[0] == "red":
        if player1[1] > player2[1]:
          player1CardsWon.append(player1)
          player1CardsWon.append(player2)
          player1.remove(0)
          player1.remove(1)
          player2.remove(0)
          player2.remove(1)
          print("Player 1 wins!")
        else:
          player2CardsWon.append(player1)
          player2CardsWon.append(player2)
          player1.remove(0)
          player1.remove(1)
          player2.remove(0)
          player2.remove(1)
          print("Player 2 wins!")
      elif player2[0] == "black": #Red beats black
        player1CardsWon.append(player1)
        player1CardsWon.append(player2)
        player1.remove(0)
        player1.remove(1)
        player2.remove(0)
        player2.remove(1)
        print("Player 1 wins!")
      elif player2[0] == "yellow": #Yellow beats black
        player2CardsWon.append(player1)
        player2CardsWon.append(player2)
        player1.remove(0)
        player1.remove(1)
        player2.remove(0)
        player2.remove(1)
        print("Player 2 wins!")
    if player1[0]== "black":
      if player2[0] == "red": #Red beats black
        player1.remove(0)
        player1.remove(1)
        player2.remove(0)
        player2.remove(1)
        print("Player 2 wins!")
      elif player2[0] == "black":
        if player1[1] > player2[1]:
          player1CardsWon.append(player1)
          player1CardsWon.append(player2)
          player1.remove(0)
          player1.remove(1)
          player2.remove(0)
          player2.remove(1)
          print("Player 1 wins!")
        else:
          player2CardsWon.append(player1)
          player2CardsWon.append(player2)
          player1.remove(0)
          player1.remove(1)
          player2.remove(0)
          player2.remove(1)
          print("Player 2 wins!")
      elif player2[0] == "yellow": #Black beats yellow
        player1CardsWon.append(player1)
        player1CardsWon.append(player2)
        player1.remove(0)
        player1.remove(1)
        player2.remove(0)
        player2.remove(1)
        print("Player 1 wins!")

'''test 3 - to check if the gamePlay function is working
deckCreator()
print(cardDeck)
deckShuffle()
print(cardDeck)
tempHold1 = cardDeck.pop(0)
tempHold2 = cardDeck.pop(0)
player1.append(tempHold1)
player2.append(tempHold2)
gamePlay()
'''

deckCreator()
deckShuffle()
gamePlay()
```

I expect the console to output:

```
Player 1 holds card red 9 for this round
Player 2 holds card black 8 for this round
Player 1 wins!
```

But it is currently outputting:

```
Player 1 holds card red 9 for this round
Player 2 holds card black 8 for this round
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/99a7da0a0b9fd10f/main.py", line 152, in <module>
    gamePlay()
  File "/tmp/sessions/99a7da0a0b9fd10f/main.py", line 92, in gamePlay
    player1.remove(0)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

(edit - This is posted from a friend's account, I don't own the account)

Comment: Please remove as much of your code from the question as you can while still being able to replicate the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It'll be much easier for someone (including you) to identify the problem if there's less code to sift through.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the remove?  You assigned player1 to refer to a card popped from the deck.  What are '0' and '1' and why do you expect them to be in player1?

Comment: For that matter, I am not sure why you need to use 'remove' at all here.  In the next round, player1 will get a new card from the deck, and it will refer to that.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.remove(x)
```

Removes the **element** whose value is `x` from the list (using equality matching to find what to remove)

`list.remove` throws the `ValueError` whenever the *thing you want to remove* does not exist in the list.

You're creating a list of lists. Each element is `[color, number]`. So once you pop from the deck you have an element like `[color, number]`. But you are trying to remove `0` (which is not a list) hence you get the error. I'm not sure why you want to call `remove` there. Those variables are going to be reassigned in the next loop anyway. You're not using the modified variables either. So just try removing those lines.

Comment: "The element x" still seems a little ambiguous. Maybe "The element with **value** x"?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you use [remove](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove). You are using an index as an argument for remove while you need to pass the element itself.

Example:

```
lst = [1,'yellow']
# If you want to remove yellow call
lst.remove('yellow')
# and not
lst.remove(1)
# If you want to remove 1 call
lst.remove(1)
# and not
lst.remove(0)
```